# Why can't the method be used in private?

Tags: ruby

Why can `update_message_business_id` method not be used under `private`?

```
class Payment < ApplicationRecord

 ...

  def self.last_payment_gathering_information(customer_thread_id, employee_user_id, business_id)
    payment = Payment.joins(:message).where("messages.customer_thread_id = ?", customer_thread_id)
       .where("messages.employee_user_id = ?", employee_user_id)
       .where(state: :gathering_information)
       .order(id: :desc).first
    payment.update_message_business_id(business_id) unless payment.nil?
    payment
  end

  private

  def update_message_business_id(business_setting_id)
    business_setting = BusinessSetting.find_by_business_id(business_setting_id)
    self.message.business_setting = business_setting
    self.message.save
  end
end

# => NoMethodError (private method `update_message_business_id' called for Payment:0x00007faac24548d0*
```

Comment: `self` refers to the class and not instance.

Comment: Why do you think it can?

Comment: Why is `last_payment_gathering_information` a class method that operates solely on `Payment.first`? Can you explain what the methods are supposed to do?

Comment: @Stefan, I simplified the method, I'll edit and put the original method. This method aims at getting the last Payment. I need to add the second method (update_message_business_id) to update the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly, it's because you call this method with the explicit receiver, which you can't do in Ruby.

To extend this answer, you can't really perform this private method call in this context, because `self` (which is always default receiver) in `last_payment_gathering_information` refers to `Payment` class, not the `Payment` instance (which has `update_message_business_id` private method).

Comment: From the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Visibility): _"A private method may not be called with a receiver, not even `self`"_

Comment: @Stefan I have to mention that this is not true about setter methods, you can do `self.foo = 'bar'` even if `foo` is private.

Comment: ok, thank you Marek. If I understand correctly, there is a kind of 'conflict' on what the 'self' refer to between the two methods ? If it works with public method but not private ones, I guess there are different mechanism when calling them. I'll do some research in that direction.

Comment: @MarekLipka that's correct. My point is that Ruby checks for an explicit receiver, not for the right context.

Comment: @MarekLipka `foo=` and `foo` are different methods.

Comment: @sawa I never said otherwise.

Comment: @MarekLipka sawa is probably referring to _"even if `foo` is private"_ which should have been _"even if `foo=` is private"_ ;-)

Comment: @MarekLipka Your "you can do `self.foo = 'bar'` even if `foo` is private" strongly implies that you take `foo=` and `foo` as the same method.

Comment: Oh, right, typo, sorry for that ;) Anyway I edited my answer, I hope it's better now. And @romss182 yes, `self` in these two contexts point to the objects of different classes.